# Visibility to sys schema objects in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In SSMS, connected with Windows Authentication and a member of an AD group that is assigned SA of the SQL Instance.

Given two different databases,

If I connect to DATABASE1 and run two queries with a 3 part object name against sys.columns, eg.

```
Select count(*) from DATABASE1.sys.columns where object_name(object_id) = 'MYTABLE' and name='MYCOLUMN'
Select count(*) from DATABASE2.sys.columns where object_name(object_id) = 'MYTABLE' and name='MYCOLUMN'
```

I see result sets from both DBs.

If I connect to DATABASE2 and run the same queries I only see results sets from DATABASE2.

What permission is preventing me from seeing DATABASE1.sys.columns while connected to DATABASE2 as a system administrator?

Comment: It likely has nothing to do with permissions, but with the fact that `OBJECT_NAME()` resolves ids local to the current database. Do a proper join on the (qualifed!) `sys.objects` instead.

Comment: That was it, duhhh...  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select count(*) from DATABASE1.sys.columns where object_name(object_id, db_id('DATABASE1')) = 'MYTABLE' and name='MYCOLUMN'
Select count(*) from DATABASE2.sys.columns where object_name(object_id, db_id('DATABASE2')) = 'MYTABLE' and name='MYCOLUMN'
```